# Dynamically change websocket URL according to server

Tags: url, dynamic, websocket, server

Did anyone try working with WebSocket? how do I change my WebSocket URL dynamically on deployment? I'm using `WS` npm for the server side with node and express.

This is my client side code for WebSocket using the WebSocket html5 API.

my WebSocket url is currently on localhost. this won't work on deployment for sure.

```
const socket = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:8080/${userID}`);

socket.onopen = function() {
  // ! from local storage or cookies get the user information
  console.log('open client');
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log(event);
};

socket.onclose = function() {
  console.log('client close');
};
```

here's the code for the `WS` npm package.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
  port: 8080,
});

const clientsId = {}; // ! client ids

wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
  // ! gets the parameters of the url
  const param = req.url;

  // ! parse the url to removed /
  const userId = param
    .split('')
    .slice(1, param.split('').length)
    .join('');

  // ! take the userId making it as a key
  // ! then the current socket connection will be the users value
  clientsId[userId] = ws;

  // ! every message will invoke this function
  // ! the incoming message are stringfy need to parse
  ws.on('message', (incomingMsg) => {
    // ! parsing the incoming msg
    incomingMsg = JSON.parse(incomingMsg);
    // ! from the incoming msg get the paired ID
    const clientPairedId = incomingMsg.pairId;
    // ! gets the socket connection from the clientsId object using the paired Id from incoming msg
    const socketPerClient = clientsId[clientPairedId];
    // ! if socketPerClient in not null
    if (socketPerClient) {
      // ! using the value from socketPerClient get the send method and use it to send the data
      socketPerClient.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          name: incomingMsg.userID,
          msg: incomingMsg.msg,
          senderId: incomingMsg.senderId,
        })
      );
      return;
    }
  });

  ws.on('close', function close() {
    console.log('disconnected server', ws.readyState);
  });
});

module.exports = wss;
```

please. help. thank you very much.